# 2 fluid block elements side by side share space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 elements which hold text, both are unknown width and I dont want to add fixed width to copy div.
How do I make them float in one line and always occupy 100% width together? (without tables)

```css
 .data{
   max-width:400px;
 }

.code {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px!important;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
}

.copy {
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px!important;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <p class="code">Praesent molestie. Nunc Venenatis Sapien Ultrices Dui. Vivamus dolor. Integer vel ante. Proin felis. Maecenas non nisl eu mi hendrerit fringilla.</p>
  <div class="copy">COPY</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.data {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline by default */
  align-items: flex-start; /* vertical alignment / optional but recommended / if you don't want that flex-items match in height, which by default they do (default value of stretch, which makes them fill the flex-containers height and where the height of all items is dictated by the height of the "tallest" one) / you can also try the value of center */
  max-width: 400px;
}

.code {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px !important;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*float: left; not necessary*/
}

.copy {
  color: #ccc;
  /*display: inline-block; not necessary*/
  padding: 3px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  /*float: right; not necessary*/
  margin-left: 10px; /* design purposes */
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <p class="code">Praesent molestie. Nunc Venenatis Sapien Ultrices Dui. Vivamus dolor. Integer vel ante. Proin felis. Maecenas non nisl eu mi hendrerit fringilla.</p>
  <div class="copy">COPY</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use flexible box to deal with this. Just need to add `display:flex` in your `.data`. For more info, please read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
 .data{
   max-width:400px;
   display:flex;
 }

.code {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px!important;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
}

.copy {
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px!important;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <p class="code">Praesent molestie. Nunc Venenatis Sapien Ultrices Dui. Vivamus dolor. Integer vel ante. Proin felis. Maecenas non nisl eu mi hendrerit fringilla.</p>
  <div class="copy">COPY</div>
</div>
```